# Java/AEM: com.day.cq.commons.Externalizer absolutelink function returning the wrong hostname

Tags: java, aem

I have an existing site hosted under www.myhost.com. I created a new "site" and using apache config/rewrites, this is hosted under new.myhost.com.

The problem is that when I make a request (example: www.myhost.com/my-servlet/lets-go), the values returned by absoluteLink function uses "new.myhost.com" instead of www.myhost.com.

I have several "com.day.cq.commons.impl.Externalizer.xml" files in my code but none of them has been configured for "new.myhost.com".

Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks

edit1: I also checked publisher configMgr and the new host is not listed in "Day CQ Link Externalizer" (pid=com.day.cq.commons.impl.ExternalizerImpl).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
          externalizer.domains="[local http://localhost:4502, author http://author.myhost.com, publish http://localhost:4503, stage http://stage.myhost.com, prod http://www.myhost.com]"
        />
```

Comment: just to be sure, have you checked on the OSGi configuration (`/system/console/configMgr`)?

Comment: @BagusTesa I edited original post. Thanks

Comment: sorry, just curious, what is the `Host` header sent to the server when the request is done? i'm wondering if it may cause different behavior.. also, please state the aem version -- i only know a bit of the legacy 5.6..